# how Do I list all table names in SQL Server using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
SELECT name FROM sys.databases  -- this can list all database name in the server


user database
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  
     -- these two line can list the table for one particular database
```

But how can I output the results like below?

```
Database              Table
---------             -------------
db1                    t1
db1                    t2
db2                    t1
...                    ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS db, * from [?].sys.tables'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stored procedure I use constantly to list all my tables ordered by the space used by them in the database.

```
GO

    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[dba_SpaceUsed]    Script Date: 03/16/2010 15:09:55 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE PROC [dbo].[dba_SpaceUsed] 

        @SourceDB varchar ( 128 ) = null -- Optional database name
             -- If omitted, the current database is reported.
      , @SortBy char(1) = 'S' -- N for name, S for Size
               -- T for table name

    AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @sql nvarchar (4000)

IF @SourceDB IS NULL BEGIN
    SET @SourceDB = DB_NAME () -- The current DB 
END

--------------------------------------------------------
-- Create and fill a list of the tables in the database.

CREATE TABLE #Tables (  [schema] sysname
                      , TabName sysname )

SELECT @sql = 'insert #tables ([schema], [TabName]) 
                  select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
                  from ['+ @SourceDB +'].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                      where TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'''
EXEC (@sql)


---------------------------------------------------------------
-- #TabSpaceTxt Holds the results of sp_spaceused. 
-- It Doesn't have Schema Info!
CREATE TABLE #TabSpaceTxt (
                         TabName sysname
                       , [Rows] varchar (11)
                       , Reserved varchar (18)
                       , Data varchar (18)
                       , Index_Size varchar ( 18 )
                       , Unused varchar ( 18 )
                       )

---------------------------------------------------------------
-- The result table, with numeric results and Schema name.
CREATE TABLE #TabSpace ( [Schema] sysname
                       , TabName sysname
                       , [Rows] bigint
                       , ReservedMB numeric(18,3)
                       , DataMB numeric(18,3)
                       , Index_SizeMB numeric(18,3)
                       , UnusedMB numeric(18,3)
                       )

DECLARE @Tab sysname -- table name
      , @Sch sysname -- owner,schema

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [SCHEMA], TabNAME 
         FROM #tables

OPEN TableCursor;
FETCH TableCursor into @Sch, @Tab;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT @sql = 'exec [' + @SourceDB 
       + ']..sp_executesql N''insert #TabSpaceTxt exec sp_spaceused '
       + '''''[' + @Sch + '].[' + @Tab + ']' + '''''''';

    Delete from #TabSpaceTxt; -- Stores 1 result at a time
    EXEC (@sql);

    INSERT INTO #TabSpace
    SELECT @Sch
         , [TabName]
         , convert(bigint, rows)
         , convert(numeric(18,3), convert(numeric(18,3), 
                left(reserved, len(reserved)-3)) / 1024.0) 
                ReservedMB
         , convert(numeric(18,3), convert(numeric(18,3), 
                left(data, len(data)-3)) / 1024.0) DataMB
         , convert(numeric(18,3), convert(numeric(18,3), 
                left(index_size, len(index_size)-3)) / 1024.0) 
                 Index_SizeMB
         , convert(numeric(18,3), convert(numeric(18,3), 
                left(unused, len([Unused])-3)) / 1024.0) 
                [UnusedMB]
        FROM #TabSpaceTxt;

    FETCH TableCursor into @Sch, @Tab;
END;

CLOSE TableCursor;
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;

-----------------------------------------------------
-- Caller specifies sort, Default is size
IF @SortBy = 'N' -- Use Schema then Table Name
    SELECT * FROM #TabSpace
       ORDER BY [Schema] asc, [TabName] asc
ELSE IF @SortBy = 'T'  -- Table name, then schema
    SELECT * FROM #TabSpace
       ORDER BY [TabName] asc, [Schema] asc
ELSE  -- S, NULL, or whatever get's the default
    SELECT * FROM #TabSpace
       ORDER BY ReservedMB desc
;

DROP TABLE #Tables
DROP TABLE #TabSpaceTxt
DROP TABLE #TabSpace
```

--Thanks to Andrew Novick

Comment: once added, run 

sp_msforeachdb 'if ''?''<>''tempdb'' exec dbo.dba_SpaceUsed ?'

Answer (score 0):

if you need one result set, try this:

```
DECLARE @AllTables table (DatabaseName sysname, TableName sysname)
DECLARE @Current sysname
       ,@SQL1    varchar(500)
       ,@SQL2    varchar(500)
       ,@SQL3    varchar(500)
       ,@SQL     varchar(1500)
SELECT TOP 1 @Current=Name FROM sys.databases Order By Name
SET @SQL1='select db.name, t.TABLE_NAME from '
SET @SQL2='.sys.databases db inner join '
SET @SQL3='.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t on db.name = t.TABLE_CATALOG'
WHILE @Current IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @SQL=@SQL1+@Current+@SQL2+@Current+@SQL3
    INSERT INTO @AllTables
        EXEC (@SQL)
    SELECT TOP 1 @Current=Name FROM sys.databases WHERE Name>@Current Order By Name
    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 BREAK
END

SELECT * FROM @AllTables ORDER BY DatabaseName,TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky enough to still be using sql2000:

```
CREATE TABLE #AllTables (DatabaseName sysname, TableName sysname)
DECLARE @Current sysname
       ,@SQL1    varchar(500)
       ,@SQL2    varchar(500)
       ,@SQL3    varchar(500)
       ,@SQL     varchar(1500)
SELECT TOP 1 @Current=Name FROM sysdatabases Order By Name
SET @SQL1='select db.name, t.TABLE_NAME from '
SET @SQL2='sysdatabases db inner join '
SET @SQL3='.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t on db.name = t.TABLE_CATALOG'
WHILE @Current IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @SQL=@SQL1+@SQL2+@Current+@SQL3
    --PRINT @SQL
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO #AllTables
        EXEC (@SQL)
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    SELECT TOP 1 @Current=Name FROM sysdatabases WHERE Name>@Current Order By Name
    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 BREAK
END

SELECT * FROM #AllTables 
--where TableName = 'at_errorlog'
ORDER BY DatabaseName,TableName

DROP TABLE #AllTables
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

Comment: Maybe this works on some version of SQL Server.  It doesn't work on 2012.